# WPF popup in NavigationWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I am building a WPF app using `NavigationWindow` with many `Page`s. I have created popups within a `Page` like follows:

XAML

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainDisplay}" Placement="Center" Name="myPopup">
    <Frame Name="popupFrame"/>
</Popup>
```

codebehind

```
popupFrame.Navigate(new MyUserControl()); //navigate to a user control
myPopup.IsOpen = true; //to "pop up" popup
```

Except now, I would like a "global" popup, which is based on a timer and can popup at any page when time is up. The timer is inside the main `NavigationWindow`'s codebehind and keeps ticking across all pages, but I cannot place the popup directly within the `NavigationWindow` since it does not support direct content. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it's very simple. I just need to create a popup in codebhind of `NavigationWindow`, and set `myPopup.IsOpen=true` when time is up.